# Decomposition of the differential graded algebra

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-algebra

Let $(V,d)$ be the finite dimensional differential graded algebra. Let $V=V_{1}\oplus V_{2},$ $d(V_{1})\subseteq V_{1}.$ If $d(v)=x+y,$ where $v$ belongs to bases of $V_{2}$ and $x\in V_{1},$   $0\neq y\in V_{2}.$ Can we write that $$(V,d)\cong (V_{1},d)\oplus (V_{2},d).$$

Comment: To be clear, you're *not* assuming that $d(V_2)\subseteq V_2$, right?  That is, $x$ could be non-zero?